# CFform and Jquery Submit Without Refresh

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a fairly simple CFform that I use to submit and add a record to my DB without a page refresh using JQuery.

My main page calls a page with the form code using #include-from-outside:

```
<div class="vehicle-log" id='include-from-outside'></div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#include-from-outside').load('trip_tab.cfm?ticketid=<cfoutput>#url.ticketid#</cfoutput>');
</script>
```

The page with the form implements jquery-tabs to show the form on one tab, and a summary of the records submitted on the other tab.

```
<!---Calendar Script--->
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#vdate" ).datepicker();
  });

   $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      //Send the serialized data to mailer.php.
      $('#addmileage').submit(function (e) 
      {          
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        data: $('#addmileage').serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        url:'actionpages/add_trip.cfm?ticketid=<cfoutput>#url.ticketid#</cfoutput>',
        success: function (response)
            {
                //do after response.
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

<!---Odometer Totaling --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/odometersum.js" language="javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Mileage Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Trips</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">

            <!---Get current ticket from DB --->
            <cfoutput>
            <cfquery name="get_ticket" datasource="#datasource#">
            select *
            from service_ticket
            where ticket_id = #url.ticketid#
            </cfquery>
            </cfoutput>

            <!---Get current trips for this ticket --->
            <cfoutput>
            <cfquery name="get_trips" datasource="#datasource#">
            select *
            from vehicle_log
            where ticket_id = '#url.ticketid#'
            </cfquery>
            </cfoutput>

            <cfquery name="get_vehicles" datasource="#datasource#">
            select *
            from vehicles
            where active = '1'
            </cfquery>

    <cfform name="addmileage" id="addmileage" method="post" class="vehicle-log-form">
             <br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="5">
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Service Vehicle:</label></td>
                        <td><cfselect class="vehicle-log-form" queryPosition="below" name="vehicle_name" id="vehicle_name" value="vehicle_name" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getData()" bindonload="true" >
                        </cfselect>                    </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Date:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" name="vdate" id="vdate" type="text" required="yes" />                          &nbsp; <a href="javascript:;" onclick="displayDatePicker('vdate');"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <label class="vehicle-log-form">Origin:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" required="yes" name="origin" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Destination:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput required="yes"  class="vehicle-log-form" name="destination" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr><!---onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getDetail({vehicle_name})" bindattribute="value" bindonload="true" ---> 
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Start Odometer:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" id="start_odometer"  name="start_odometer" type="text"  /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr><!---onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getDetail({vehicle_name})" bindattribute="value" bindonload="true" --->
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">End Odometer:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form"  id="end_odometer" name="end_odometer" type="text"  /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Total mileage:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" id="total_mileage" name="total_mileage" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Expenses:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" value="0.00" name="expenses" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        <!---If ticket isn't saved yet, disable the button --->
                        <cfif #get_ticket.recordcount# eq '0'>
                        <cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Trip"  disabled="disabled"/> 
                        <span class="style3">Ticket must be saved first.</span>
                        <cfelse>
                       <cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Trip">
                        </cfif>                        </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
    </cfform>




  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">



 <!---Get current trips for this ticket --->
            <cfoutput>
            <cfquery name="get_trips" datasource="#datasource#">
            select *
            from vehicle_log
            where ticket_id = '#url.ticketid#'
            </cfquery>
            </cfoutput>

            <br />
<br />

            <cfif #get_trips.recordcount# eq 0>
            <table width="100%" class="vehicle-log-table" id="vehicle-log-table" border="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr class="vehicle-log-table" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center"><strong>Date</strong></div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center"><strong>Mileage</strong></div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center"><strong>Expenses</strong></div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="right"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="vehicle-log-table">
                  <td colspan="4">No Trips Exist</td>
                </tr>
                </table><br />

            <cfelse>    
                <table width="100%" class="vehicle-log-table" border="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr class="vehicle-log-table" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center"><strong>Date</strong></div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center"><strong>Mileage</strong></div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center"><strong>Expenses</strong></div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="right"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <cfoutput>
                <cfloop query="get_trips">

                <tr class="vehicle-log-table">
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table">#DateFormat(get_trips._date, "mm-dd-yyyy")#</td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center">#get_trips.total_mileage#</div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="center">#get_trips.expenses#</div></td>
                  <td class="vehicle-log-table"><div align="right"> 
                  <cfform name="delete" action="">
                  <cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete">
                  <cfinput type="hidden" id="hidden" name="hidden" value="#get_trips.id#">
                  </cfform>           
                 </div></td>
                </tr>



            </cfloop>
            </cfoutput>
          </table><br />
</cfif>
```

When a user clicks the submit button, it submits without an error or a page refresh and successfully adds a record to my DB.

But how can I get just the jquery-tabs element to refresh to show the newly added record? I am sure this is simple but I am a jquery newbie.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Two CF tips for you: 1. You don't need to wrap your `<cfquery>` tags inside `<cfoutput></cfoutput>`.  2. You don't usually need to wrap references to your CF variables in `##` in most `<cf...>` tags, e.g. `<cfif #get_ticket.recordcount# eq '0'>` can be rewritten as `<cfif get_ticket.recordcount eq '0'>` (or even just `<cfif NOT get_ticket.recordcount>`)

Comment: variables don't need to be wrapped? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: they dont need to be wrapped unless you need to evaluate them.  so if you're in a string `<cfset temp = "this is my #form.name#" />` then it needs the `#`. However, if you are just using them in code, as in a cfif then you don't need them.  Typically, if you're in a string (between "" or '') then you'll need them, good rule of thumb, although that also has its exceptions (looping over a query most notably)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is that I make the ajax call give me an HTML where I put the data with the format I want so all styles can apply there. If you are using some MVC framework, you call your controller in the ajax, then you process that data, send to the DB and return an HTML with the data you want to show in your response there. Once you get your response and it is an HTML you just do this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $('#addmileage').serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    url:'actionpages/add_trip.cfm?ticketid=<cfoutput>#url.ticketid#</cfoutput>',
    success: function (response)
        {
            $(ElementOrElementsYouWantToRefresh).html(response)
        }
    });
```

So in this way you place the html that your response gives you into the element you want to place the content. What I am doing is changing the HTML content of the element or elements you want so they show the response of your ajax call

Comment: I'm not sure I followed that at all. Is having my form code on a seperate page making this unecessarily difficuly? OR is there a way to  just tell the tabs element to reload?

Comment: I tried: success: function() {$("#tabs").tabs(''refresh');} BUT that doesn't seem to work. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You need to change your element's html content. As I said, I make my ajax call return an html where I previously parsed the data fetched from the db or server. After that, I make my element change it's html content for the response of the ajax call, that's the way it refreshes.

Comment: What backend are you using? what framework? maybe you can tell me so I can help you better.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion on the backend. The form submits without issue, but the form stays filled with the submitted content. If I could get the tab element to refresh, it would show the user that the submit actually did something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by change your elements html content. Do you mean the tab element? What am I changing exactly? My action page is not returning anything as we'll.